# Fable Bindings for react-beautiful-dnd throwing error building Droppable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, f#, fable-f#

I'm trying to write Fable binders for the [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) library, and I'm stuck on how to bind the [Droppable](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/droppable.md) component because it requires a function to create the children rather than have the children supplied directly like most other components.

I'm referencing [this react example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k260nyxq9v?file=/index.js), where the component looks like this (see line 70 on that link):

```js
render() {
    return (
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <div
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
            >
              {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                 <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id} index={index}>
                  {(provided, snapshot) => (
                    <div
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.draggableProps}
                      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                      style={getItemStyle(
                        snapshot.isDragging,
                        provided.draggableProps.style
                      )}
                    >
                      {item.content}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </Draggable>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    );
```

So instead of just providing children directly, I need to provide a function of `(DroppableProvided, DroppableStateSnapshot) -> ReactElement`. Here is what I have so far:

```
type DroppableStateSnapshot = {
    isDraggingOver : bool
}

type DroppableProvided = {
    innerRef : Browser.Types.Element -> unit
}

type IDroppableAttribute = interface end
type droppable =
    static member inline droppableId (id : string) = unbox<IDroppableAttribute>("droppableId", id)
    static member inline childrenFn (f : (DroppableProvided * DroppableStateSnapshot) -> ReactElement) =
        unbox<IDroppableAttribute>("children", f)

[<Erase>]
type Droppable() =
    static member inline droppable (id : string) props (childrenFn: (DroppableProvided * DroppableStateSnapshot) -> ReactElement) =
        let _id = droppable.droppableId id
        let f = droppable.childrenFn childrenFn
        let props = keyValueList CaseRules.LowerFirst (_id :: (f :: props))
        ofImport "Droppable" "react-beautiful-dnd"  props []
```

I directly created the snapshot and provided types instead of trying to import them because I'm pretty sure I just need something with the right properties as the arguments to the `childrenFn` function.

Finally, here is a component using the `droppable` component I defined, providing a function to create the child element:

```
[<ReactComponent>]
let TestDroppable() =
  Droppable.droppable "test-droppable" [] (fun (provided, snapshot) ->
    div [ Ref provided.innerRef ] [
      BuildDraggable 0 [p [] [ str "This is the first item"]]
      BuildDraggable 1 [p [] [ str "This is the second item"]]
      BuildDraggable 2 [p [] [ str "This is the third item"]]
      BuildDraggable 3 [p [] [ str "This is the fourth item"]]
    ])
```

When I run this in the browser, I get an error of `Uncaught TypeError: provided is undefined`, pointing to the line where I set the `Ref` property. I'm doing this because the docs say you *have* to provide a `ref` value (see the "Children Function" section of the Droppable docs I linked). The stack trace shows this function being invoked *from* `react-beautiful-dnd`, so I can at least be reasonably sure I'm loading & executing the library.

So it seems like the function is being invoked by the framework correctly, but with null arguments. I don't know if this error is because of binding wrong, building the component wrong, not importing the right things, or some other combination of errors when working with the imported library.

The full source code is available [here](https://github.com/PaigeM89/Fable.React.DragAndDrop/blob/main/src/Fable.React.Beautiful.Dnd/Library.fs). I am putting this whole thing inside a `DragDropContext`, which seems to bind without issue.

Comment: I cloned and built your repository. What should I run to reproduce what you're seeing?

Comment: @brianberns Run `yarn start` from the `src/Fable.React.Beautiful.Dnd` directory and navigate to `localhost:8090`, then check the dev console (nothing will render due to the error). Note you may need to run `dotnet tool restore`, `dotnet paket install`, and/or `yarn install` first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any Fable/React experience, so I could be way off, but this F# code looks suspect to me:

```
type IDroppableAttribute = interface end

unbox<IDroppableAttribute>("children", f)
```

In a normal runtime environment, this will throw an `InvalidCastException`, because the `Tuple` type doesn't implement `IDroppableAttribute`. I don't know what happens when it's translated to Javascript instead, but I suspect it won't work there either.

Comment: Oh it's weird to me too. I copied that pattern from some [known fable react libraries](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Feliz/blob/a087159f03158f23e98101d9eecfa7bdad822563/Feliz.SelectSearch/SelectSearch.fs#L153), hoping the purpose would become clearer as I worked with it more. It does error in FSI but works fine in try.fsharp.org, which is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in JavaScript is a [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

You should simply include in a new prop named `render` matching your signature: `childrenFn: (DroppableProvided * DroppableStateSnapshot) -> ReactElement`

I haven't try it but it's usually this way.
Also I advise reading the [react website](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) as it helps understand what's happening on the other side of the fence when using fable.